# Show all store categories in sidebar on product listing page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sidebar, filtered-nav

When I click on the parent category 'shoes' I am able to filter by sub categories within the parent category ('shoes') only. I would like to see all categories and sub-categories in the sidebar.

Can anyone please assist with a solution to displaying all categories in the sidebar of my Magento store?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in your theme’s catalog XML file like this:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/my_left_nav.phtml" />
</refrence>
```

It should be placed inside the reference name “left“, to show it in the left sidebar. I hope you know all these stuffs. Let’s get to the point. Just copy and paste the code in the `my_left_nav.phtml`, which should be in your theme’s `catalog/navigation` folder.

```
<!-- List all categories and their second level subcategories -->
<div class="block block-list block-categories">
    <div id="block-categories" class="block-title active">
        <strong><span>Categories </span></strong>
    </div>

<div id="leftnav" class="block-content" style="display:block">
    <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
        <ul id="leftnav-tree" class="level0">
            <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                <li class="level0<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></span></a>
                    <?php //if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>
                        <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
                        <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                            <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>" class="level1">
                                <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
                                    <li class="level1<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($subcategory)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                         <?php $secondLevelSubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
                                         <?php if (count($secondLevelSubcategories ) > 0): ?>
                            <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $subcategory->getId() ?>" class="level2">
                                <?php foreach($secondLevelSubcategories as $secondLevelSubcategory ): ?>
                                    <li class="level2<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($secondLevelSubcategory )): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($secondLevelSubcategory ) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($secondLevelSubcategory ->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php //endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree', 'recursive')</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response Aruendra. However, this still only shows category options for the children of the parent category I am in. I want to show all categories in the left sidebar, regardless of the category the user is in.

Answer (score -1):

proxiblue's link doesn't work anymore.
Still free here:
https://www.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/sidebar-navigation-menu-professional/

Just tested with 1.9 and it still works. Except the original left navigation menu is still there. I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of that.